# How can I get the Dust to Dust achievement?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

In Assassin's Creed Brotherhood there are five hidden artifacts in the Monteriggioni villa, and finding any of them unlocks the Dust to Dust achievement.

Where can I find them?

Comment: @badp: You've edited it so this isn't the same intent at all anymore. It used to be (an admittedly vague) "What is there to do at Monteriggioni?" and the answer was "Get the Dust to Dust achievement." Now it's "How do I get the Dust to Dust achievement?" and the answer is "Explore Monteriggioni."

Comment: erm, lol? i have no problem with people editing my questions, but I also don't get why you change the question + the correct answer. just so its shorter?

Comment: @JoeWreschnig The original question didn't even mention Monteriggioni. Atticae: no, it's to avoid having to close it.

Comment: @badp: "Now in Brotherhood as Desmond you can run through the city for 10 minutes" - "The city" is Monteriggioni. I am not adverse to editing the question to remove the nebulous request for _any_ missable easter eggs, but you've completely inverted the question and answer. The question is now full of more spoilers than the answer.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Sorry, I haven't played every game out there. Feel free to suggest your edits :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one thing I know of to do in Monteriggioni during your limited exploration, aside from the mandatory plot points and the email.

> There are five items, remnants of the villa from before the battle.

They are found at:

> Maria's Feather Chest: On the villa's roof. Mario's Sword: Under a tree on the street. Ezio's Belt: Far right corner of the city facing the gates from the villa. Medici Cape: Left of the villa, inside a church. Record Book: Inside the villa on the right.

For finding them, you get:

> A trophy/achievement, *Dust to Dust*, for the first one you find, and as far as I know, nothing else for the rest.

Comment: As I recall, the belt is very hard to see. It seems to be lying in a refuse heap and is hard to distinguish.